# Help Interpreting a group by clause

Tags: sql-server

I have the following Group By clause:

Group By
Grouping Sets (a, (b, Rollup (c, d)) )

My thought process is

Grouping sets ( a )
Union All
Grouping sets( (b, Rollup (c, d) ) )

Then expand the latter into 
Grouping sets ( (b, ( (c,d), (c), ( () ) )

Then do a Cartesian product, so the second part becomes
Grouping sets ( (b, c,d), (b,c), (b) ).

Overall, the equivalent expression would be

Grouping sets (a, bcd, bc, b).

Please help me point out which step is incorrect.

Thanks

Comment: Please post table scripts, sample data and expected output. See http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ for guidance.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/craigfr/2007/09/21/aggregation-with-rollup/